# Convert a UK postal code to a city name?

Tags: geocoding, web-service, united-kingdom, postal-code

Is there any service to convert a UK postal code to a city name? Does one postal code always map to one city, or to more than one? Is there a free web service to do this conversion for me?

Comment: Postcodes go down to a number of clusters of Addresses. The more urban the closer they are together.

Comment: 10 Downing Street (SW1A 2AA) returns London, UK http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW1A%202AA&sensor=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Bing Geocoder, I believe they do UK, so you should be able to look up the coordinates of the zip code and in the results you will see the cities that correspond globally to that zip code...

P.S., Don't use google geocoder for UK, it doesn't work properly from personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

[Mapsdata](http://www.mapsdata.co.uk) and other similar services allow you to load up Postcode and attribute data in .xls or .csv format for free and then view it on a map if that's the end product that you're looking for.

Here's a [wiki description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_areas_in_the_United_Kingdom) of how the postal code system works using the first or first and secondary alpha characters.  It's regional specific and not city, ie PH is the administrative district of Perthshire which also contains the city of Perth.

The [Ordnance Survey](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point/index.html) is also a good resource on this.